# How do you adjust the kerning of a C4Label?

Tags: ios, c4

There doesn't seem to be a property to change the kerning. Is the best way to get the UILabel from C4Label and then go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes.

`C4Label` was originally designed when iOS5 was out, and didn't need any modifying when iOS6 was released... Prior to iOS6 the use of attributed strings was unavailable in `UILabel`. Since `C4Label` essentially wraps an instance of `UILabel` it, too, didn't (and still doesn't) have direct access to the use of attributed strings.

However, given `C4Label` wraps `UILabel` is possible to add kerning in the following way:

```
-(void)setup {
    //Create a label
    C4Label *l = [C4Label labelWithText:@"this is kerning"];
    l.numberOfLines = 2;

    //Create a key
    NSString *kernKey = (NSString *)kCTKernAttributeName;
    //Create a value
    NSNumber *kernValue = @20;
    //Create an attributed string
    NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [NSMutableAttributedString new];
    //set the attributed string with the text, using the value as a dictionary
    attStr = [attStr initWithString:l.text attributes:@{kernKey:kernValue}];

    //set and center the text
    l.label.attributedText = attStr;
    l.textAlignment = ALIGNTEXTCENTER;

    //resize and position the frame
    l.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320, 80);
    l.center = self.canvas.center;

    [self.canvas addLabel:l];
}
```

C4Label is on the list for being modernized, but hasn't been gotten to yet.